# Dar um select para retornar os valores exclusivos

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Possuo vários valores repetidos,o valor pode ter status(diferente ou  diferenciado) ou posso ter dois valores com status diferentes/diferenciado, e preciso fazer uma comparação entre eles(no caso utilizo uma chave), que para isso preciso retornar as exclusivas que são diferenciados e que não pode haver a mesma informação no status diferente. Eu tentei fazer esse select, porém não sei o que pode estar de errado...

```
SELECT * from teste WHERE chave IN (select distinct(chave) from teste group by chave having count(chave) > 1) AND chave NOT IN (select distinct(chave) from teste where status = 'diferente')
```

EXEMPLO:

CHAVE  | STATUS 
ABC123 | DIFERENCIADO
ABC123 | DIFERENTE
ACB321 | DIFERENCIADO
ACB321 | DIFERENTE
ACC231 | DIFERENTE -> este dado que eu gostaria de retornar

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi você quer apenas trazer os valores com status = "DIFERENTE" e que não possua chave no status "diferenciado"?

Comment: Poste uma tabelinha com 2 campos e 5 valores para dar uma idéia do que você chama de diferente ou diferenciado e outra com o resultado que você espera.

Comment: Alterei no post, não sei se ficou claro. Muito obrigado pela atenção Aprendiz e Reginaldo.

Comment: E se tivesse dois registros ACC231?

Comment: Ele teria que retornar do mesmo jeito, mas só se estivesse com o status DIFERENTE. Pode acontecer desse dado ACC231 estar duplicado com o mesmo status.

Comment: mas o ACB321 tem DIFERENTE no status, voce quer que retorne tambem?

Answer (score 1):

Segue o script, tente utilizar assim

```
 SELECT CHAVE,
        STATUS
   FROM teste
  WHERE status = 'DIFERENTE'
    AND CHAVE NOT IN
        (SELECT CHAVE
         FROM teste
         WHERE STATUS = 'DIFERENCIADO')
```

**Resultado:**

ACC231  DIFERENTE

Answer (score 0):

Alternativamente, usando cláusulas `WITH` (alguns acham mais fácil de raciocinar assim):

```
with diferentes as (
    select chave
      from teste
     where status = 'DIFERENTE'
), diferenciados as (
    select chave
      from teste
     where status = 'DIFERENCIADO'
)
select chave
  from diferentes
 where chave not in (
         select chave
           from diferenciados
       )
;
```

Alternativamente, com `EXCEPT`:

```
select chave
  from teste
 where status = 'DIFERENTE'
except
select chave
  from teste
 where status = 'DIFERENCIADO'
;
```

O `EXCEPT` é como se fosse um `UNION` ao contrário: em vez de concatenar as linhas da segunda *query* à da primeira, ele **remove** as linhas da primeira *query* que coincidam com alguma da segunda.  Assim como o `UNION`, a lista da cláusula `SELECT` tem que bater em ambas as *queries*.